# opencart trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: opencart

I'm running open cart 2.3 on PHP 7.2
I got this message
trying to access array offset on value of type bool in startup.php line 171
the code is :

```
if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address'])) {
            $this->tax->setShippingAddress($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'], $this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id']);
        }
```

could anyone suggest a solution

Comment: You could Better Format your Question. The error points to startup.php file but you have given the code from somewhere else. Please check your code in file startup.php at Line Number 171.

Comment: I agree , in that code there does not appear to be any accessing an array's element that is the result of a function that might return boolean

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

```
if (isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id']) && isset($this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'])){
        $this->tax->setShippingAddress($this->session->data['shipping_address']['country_id'], $this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better fix would be

```
if (is_array($this->session->data['shipping_address'])) {
```

Somehow the value on this is `false` instead of `null`